# API rate limiting issue

Tags: instagram

I am always and constantly getting the following error when trying to follow a user via instagram although the 5000 request limit hasn't been exceeded. Why is this?

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APIError","code":400,"error_message":"Client request limit reached"}}
```

Comment: I have the same issue and have no idea how to fix that at the moment. I just emailed them to ask if there is somehow a way to whitelist the app.

Answer (score 3):

While API request with access token is 5000 (any API call), certain API like follow, unfollow, like, comment are limited to 350 an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I sent post requets from server side (google app engine) and now I am sending post requests from client (with js) and it works well.

Comment: are you then storing the access token on javascript? so then can everyone see your token?

Comment: Server store access_token and js take it when need. Yes, if you look at code of page you can see your access_token. May be it is not the best practice, but it is only start

Comment: i don't follow and don't like a lot (may be 50 per day)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your request. Instagram has a new API limit, 100 likes/hr, 60 follow/unfollow/hr IF you authenticate server side and sign your headers, check out the Instragram authentication for developers.

I'm currently running a website: http://instapromobiz.com that automates likes/follows/unfollows using these restrictions. It works great, check it out.